# I have two String and need to compare with words

Tags: java

```
String first-word="they will win";

String second-word="will they";

String[] spiltfirstWord= firstWord.split("\\s+");

String[] spiltsecondWord= secondWord.split("\\s+");
```

I tried with splitting the string , but the blocker for me is the words are at different index.

in Output i need to print "win"

Comment: You mean you want to get the words that are present in one string but not the other?

Comment: By the way, hypens are not allowed in the identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `List<String>` instead of Arrays, it simplifies your life under any point of view.

With this code you can reach your goal

```
    String firstWord="they will win";
    String secondWord="will they";

    List<String> firstList = Arrays.asList(firstWord.split("\\s+"));
    List<String> secondList = Arrays.asList(secondWord.split("\\s+"));
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for( String word : firstList){
        if(!secondList.contains(word)){
            result.add(word);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

> [win]

PS: you can substitute the for cicle with java 8 lambdas

```
    List<String> result = firstList.stream()
            .filter(word -> !secondList.contains(word))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can just try `collect(Collectors.toList())` instead of creating a list first

Comment: Good tip, edited ! ;)

Comment: Also you must be aware of the fact that `Arrays.asList` will return a *fake* list which lots of ordinary list operations are not supported. [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)

Answer (score 0):

You should map the first String into a array of String and the other one String into a Set of String.    It would ease and would do more efficient the matching operation.

It would give such a logic :

```
String firstWord = "they will win";
String secondWord = "will they";

Set<String> splitsecondWord = Arrays.stream(secondWord.split("\\s+"))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<String> missingWords = Arrays.stream(firstWord.split("\\s+"))
                                .filter(s -> !splitsecondWord.contains(s))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(missingWords);
```

Output :

> [win]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using `Pattern` and `stream`

```
    Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
    String firstWord = "they will win";
    String secondWord = "will they";
    List<String> secondWordList = splitter.splitAsStream(secondWord).collect(Collectors.toList());

    splitter.splitAsStream(firstWord)
            .filter(w -> !secondWordList.contains(w))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do very easy and simple

```
 String firstword = "they will win one day";
        String secondword = "will they";
        List<String> diff = Arrays.stream(firstword.split("\\s+")).filter(s -> !secondword.contains(s))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(diff); // output [win, one, day]
```